# Blazor: have a child component update properties of a model in its parent

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I'm looking for is a way to edit a parameter of a class/model instance that persists in a parent from a child of that parent.

I have a component that is suppose to handle editing of strings, these strings are more often than not parts of larger models.

lets say I have these models:

```
 public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
public class Arena
{
    public string Name;
    public string Location;
}
```

my parent component looks something like this:
the .cs part (named: Parent.razor.cs):

```
public partial class Paren : ComponentBase
{
    public Arena myArena;
    public Customer myCustomer;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        myArena = new Arena() { Location = "Centrum", Name = "TheBigGlobe" };
        myCustomer = new Customer() { FirstName = "kalle", LastName = "anka" };
    }
}
```

and its .razor part (named: Parent.razor)

```
<h1>component test</h1>
@if(myArena != null)
{
    //pass paramenter by ref to child
}
```

How can I create a child component that can bind it's changes to an instance and property of a unknown model in the parent?

for example how can make I child component be able to take a reference to myArena.Name as a paramenter and then update it at the parent component? note that it's important that the reference passed to the child could be any other parameter from any other class-instance.

what I'm looking for is a way to edit a parameter of a class/model instance that persists in a parent from a child of that parent.

Comment: Why don't using `ViewBag`?

Comment: @MohammadFarahi i don't think ViewBag is available in Blazor, or is it?

Comment: can you show what is inside the child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily create a child component and pass an arena parameter.

```
 <childComponent arena={myArena}> </childComponent> 

@code { 

   [parameter] public Arena arena {get; set;}
}
```

if you want to get modified data arena from child component you can use EventCallBack.

Here is an article that described few ways to [communicates between two components.](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/)

Comment: where hoping that there would be a way to only pass a reference of a property in arena to the child so that any changes made in the child would also change the parent, but i guess that's to much to ask atm :) thx 4 your answer!